# How to have Header get box shadow after scrolling 'x' ammount

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the header to have a shadow after I scroll down the page 'x' amount. I have a JSFiddle included at the bottom with the script I have been trying to use.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(window).scroll(function() {
     if ($(document).scrollTop() >= 100) {
        $('#header').addClass('mdl-shadow--4dp');
     }
  });
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p0qqukw6/)

Comment: @KaanBurakSener He doesn't need to, he loaded it as an external resources. Its a class material design lite has, the reason his scrolling doesn't work has something to do with loading one of those frameworks, something am trying to solve now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as soon as I took your JS fiddle code locally, and forgot to load your external resources. I was alerting on scroll, and I was getting those alerts, but once I loaded your external resources the scroll events broke.

So I knew it has something to do with one of the frameworks, and figured out its material-design-lite. Someone experienced this issue before and opened an issue about on their github repo [here](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/1166)

The solution is to capture the scroll events on `'mdl-layout'` instead of document & window

checkout this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p0qqukw6/1/)

Comment: PERFECT! Is there anyway to have it remove the class after you scroll up to the same point or no?

Comment: @OwenDunnigan ofcourse! Checkout my updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p0qqukw6/2/) !

Comment: @OwenDunnigan You are more than welcome! I was more than glad to help because I didn't know scroll events were this awesome!